# ToUpper() in an Expression.Call

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The code below work, but I'd like introduce a `ToUpper()`

```
var predicate =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "FirstName"),
            "Contains", null,
            Expression.Constant("myvalue".ToUpper())), parameter
        );
```

The result is :

```
{Param_0 => Param_0.FirstName.Contains("MYVALUE")}
```

But I'd like this :

```
{Param_0 => Param_0.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains("MYVALUE")}
```

How can I change ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add an `Expression.Call`:

```
var predicate =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.Call( // <=== this one is new
                Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "FirstName"),
                "ToUpper", null),
            "Contains", null,
            Expression.Constant("myvalue".ToUpper())), parameter
        );
```

which then reports itself as:

```
Param_0 => Param_0.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains("MYVALUE")
```

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Okay, I'd misread the question. The problem is that you're calling `Contains` directly on the result of calling the `FirstName` property. You need to call `ToUpper` on the property first, e.g.

```
var firstName = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "FirstName");
var firstNameUpper = Expression.Call(firstName, "ToUpper", null);
var target = Expression.Constant("myvalue".ToUpper());
var contains = Expression.Call(firstNameToUpper, "Contains", null, target);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(contains, parameter);
```

Note that this isn't "culturally-safe" - it would be safer to use a case-insensitive comparison instead. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring) shows an approach using `IndexOf`, but that may not be supported by your LINQ provider (I don't know what you're doing with this expression tree afterwards).

Comment: Thanks Jon. But it's not the result I want. I'd like make a ToUpper() on the values coming from "FirstName" before do the a "Contains" where the string is already uppercase.

Comment: Jon, or if it's easier do a "Contains" with an IgnoreCase

Comment: @Kris-I: I've edited the answer for the tree you were looking for, but I'll see if I can find a better approach.