# call ToUpper in expression tree LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, expression-trees, toupper

I would like to create this LINQ query:

```
    Result = Result.Where(Function(Row) Convert.ToString(Row(0)).ToUpper = "TEST")
```

I have this query already:

```
Result = Result.Where(Function(Row) Convert.ToString(Row(0)) = "TEST")
```

with this code:

```
expr = Expression.Call(whereMethod, Result.AsQueryable.Expression,
       Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(convertMethod, Expression.ArrayAccess(rowParameter, Expression.Constant(index))),
       Expression.Constant(constant)), rowParameter))
```

The `convertMethod` represents `Convert.ToString`, the `index` has the value 0, and `constant` has the value "TEST".

Now, I would like to add to this expression the ToUpper method.

I declared this:

`convertMethod_toupper = GetType(String).GetMethod("ToUpper", New Type() {GetType(Object)}`)

And I found this: [ToUpper in an Expression call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986573/toupper-in-an-expression-call)

I should also call the ToUpper method after the `Convert.ToString(Row(0))` with calling Expression.Call one more time. But how?

Thanks.

EDIT: in the meantime, I figured out, that this returns null too:

```
convertMethod_toupper = GetType(String).GetMethod("ToUpper", New Type() {GetType(Object)})
```

What is wrong with this?

If this should not be null, I think, this should be working:

```
expr = Expression.Call(whereMethod, Result.AsQueryable.Expression,
       Expression.Lambda(Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(Expression.Call(convertMethod, Expression.ArrayAccess(rowParameter, Expression.Constant(index))), convertMethod_toupper),
       Expression.Constant(constant)), rowParameter))
```

EDIT2: I got it.

```
convertMethod_toupper = GetType(String).GetMethod("ToUpper", System.Type.EmptyTypes)
```

and the above expression (in edit1) works.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841226/case-insensitive-string-compare-in-linq-to-sql ?

Comment: What is this: Row(0) ? Is that System.Data.DatRow or DataGridViewRow or ... ?

Comment: Does EDIT2 mean that your code now works?